# How do I update variables in instantiated objects that are instantiated from the same class in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to store variables in the object of a class rather than in the variable in the class.

For example, I want to use the same method for both object instances of Account (account1 and account2). But using the following code, account1 and account2 have the same values. How can I make it so that only account1 updates while having just one accountBalance variable in the class?

```
public class Account{

int accountBalance;

public void updateAccountBalance{
this.accountBalance += 5;
}

public Account{
this.accountBalance;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
Account account1 = new Account();
Account account2 = new Account();

for(i = 0, i < 10, i++){
account1.updateAccountBalance();
}
System.out.println(account1.accountBalance);
System.out.println(account2.AccountBalance);

}
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. For example, `updateAccountBalance {` is missing its brackets - it should be `updateAccountBalance() {`. Please correct basic compilation errors and formatting.

Comment: @theoneseeker, it seems like your old question was deleted. If you have any questions regard it you could check out my [github](https://github.com/darclander) and add my Discord if you want further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
class Account {

    int accountBalance;

    public void updateAccountBalance() {
        this.accountBalance += 5;
    }

    public int getAccount() {
        return this.accountBalance;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Account account1 = new Account();
        Account account2 = new Account();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            account1.updateAccountBalance();
        }

        System.out.println(account1.getAccount());
        System.out.println(account2.getAccount());
    }
}
```

Comment: You've created a method with the same name as a class, that is incredibly confusing. Please change that to `getAccount()` instead.